# Automatically identify tracks in an MP3 collection

Tags: windows, music, mp3

I need a program for Windows 8.1 with no bloatware or adware that will automatically rename, tag, and add cover art to my MP3 collection.  I want something to do this by auto AcoustID or fingerprinting of the songs.

I have [MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/) and [Picard](https://picard.musicbrainz.org/), but I can't get them to do this automatically.

Some of the names are wrong, and the tags in many of the files are incomplete or missing.

Comment: What's the issue with MusicBrainZ Picard? It's supposed to do file tagging.

Answer (score 1):

[SongKong](http://www.jthink.net/songkong) is designed to identify and rename music files and add cover art, and it can recognize them if the audio has no ID3 tag and is named "track1.mp3" using *Acoustic Fingerprinting*

It can be used on a collection of any size, and runs without requiring any other software on OSX and Windows.

Disclaimer: **I am the SongKong developer**.